# Common Button on Ribbon tabs wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, button, ribbon

I'm using Ribbon in my WPF application. Is there any change that I can have the same button on every tab or Ribbon? I don't want to create exactly the same seperately and handle it every time. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

In that situation how would differentiate between the buttons and their "click" events? Really the best way to handle this is to create a ViewModel with a series of ICommands to handle the different button functions. It will make it a million times easier to test later and much easier to view instead of following the spaghetti code of all of the "Button_Click" events.